# gcc std::regex with -fpack-struct seg faults

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Consider the following simple c++ program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::regex foobar( "[A]+");

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with -fpack-struct=1 it seg faults

```
g++-5 -std=gnu++14 ./fpack_regex.cpp -fpack-struct=1 -o a.out && a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

While

```
g++-5 -std=gnu++14 ./fpack_regex.cpp -o a.out && a.out
```

works just fine.

Any clue why the pack-struct=1 option might cause this failure?

Comment: GCC has historically had lots of problems wih `<regex>`. What is the exact version of your GCC?

Comment: Given `g++-5`, that's probably gcc 5.something. Crashes with gcc 7 as well. With this option changing the alignment of all classes and structs, it's not surprising that given a bunch of code coming from templates in header files, it ends up compiling differently than another bunch of code that's sitting inside the library that's compiled with default options; and what we end up having here is a failure to communicate...

Comment: Is `<regex>` a header-only library? Or does it also involve some object files in standard library? In the latter case it woudn't be surprising at all if it failed when you changed such options.

Comment: @neilbutterworth g++-5 (SUSE Linux) 5.3.1 20160301 [gcc-5-branch revision 233849] although as Sam pointed out it's in other versions

Comment: Also crashes with cygwin: g++ (GCC) 5.4.0

Comment: Oops I didn't realise what you were asking about - I thought you were asking about compilation problems - the executable does crash when built with TDM GCC 5.1.0. In future, don't put the whole compile/link/execute comand on one command line please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch -fpack-struct can be very dangerous, eg. see gcc documentation warning about it:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

The main problem I see is that your code is not binary compatible with standard library (it is usually not compiled with structs packed), so calls (with transfering structs) to it may fail (as they actually do).

It is recommended not to pack all structs with this switch, but if you need packing structure, pack only those you need. I also read that recompiling libstd and/or libs you use with the same fpack-struct could help, but that is a risky option anyway.

Some information is also here (an old gcc bug concerning fpack-struct), it is outdated, but may be useful: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14173

Comment: I think you're correct that I'm hitting a compatibility problem across my binary and libstdc++.